# Media Queries para Menu

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Estou desenvolvendo uma página que possui um menu que deve exibir comportamentos diferentes de acordo as dimensões da tela. Eu vou tentar exibir isso através de algumas imagens.

No estado inicial do menu (e com uma dimensão de tela cuja largura for maior que 1000px) eu devo exibir a seguinte estrutura:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os links Pessoal, Empresarial e Governamental possuem sublinks que serão exibidos através da pseudo-classe :hover, conforme vocês podem ver na seguinte imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não tenho problema com esta estrutura. O problema que enfrento diz respeito aos estilos que devem ser carregados quando a largura da tela for menor que 700px. O que acontece é que ao invés de exibir os itens Pessoal, Empresarial e Governamental, eu devo exibir somente um link chamado "Categorias":
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O hover no link "Categorias" deve expandir todos os menus abaixo, como se percebe na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha estrutura inicial é a seguinte:

```css
*{
 list-style: none;
}
nav{
 width: 100%;
}
nav ul li{
 float: left;
}
nav ul li a{
 padding: 10px;
}
nav ul li ul{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
}
nav ul li ul li{
 float: left;
}
nav ul li ul li ul li{
 clear: left;
}
nav ul li ul li ul li a{
 color: #000;
}
nav ul li:hover ul{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#">CATEGORIAS</a>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#">PESSOAL</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Pessoal 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pessoal 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pessoal 3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">EMPRESARIAL</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Empresarial 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Empresarial 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Empresarial 3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">GOVERNAMENTAL</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Gov 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gov 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gov 3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Como vocês podem ver, a estrutura do comportamento que deve ser exibido quando a largura da tela for menor que 700px já está basicamente pronta. O lance é que eu não estou conseguindo esconder o link "Categorias" e ainda assim exibir os seus subitens Pessoal, Empresarial e Governamental ao lado esquerdo do item Contato, que é o que eu exibo nas duas primeiras imagens.

Vocês podem me ajudar? Obrigado!!!